# Custom user creation form always invalid in Django

Tags: python, django

I am working on building a new Django Website and am trying to make an abstract base class and using forms to fill it out. I thought I was doing it correctly, but whenever I try to fill out the form it is always invalid. I am wondering if anyone can help me with this problem. All of the other help I find online does not help me. Here is my code. Thanks

My forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .models import Profile

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

    def __init__(self, regLinkModel):
        super(CustomUserCreationForm, self).__init__()
        self.linkInfo = regLinkModel

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(CustomUserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['fname']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['lname']
        user.password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        user.password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']
          
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

My Models.py

```
class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, first_name, last_name, password):
        if not email:
             raise ValueError("User needs email address")
        if not username:            
             raise ValueError("User needs username")
        if not first_name:            
            raise ValueError("User needs first name")
        if not last_name:            
            raise ValueError("User needs last name")
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password = password,
            username =username,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
        )

        user.set_password(password1)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password, first_name, last_name):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password = password,
            username =username,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def count_total_profiles(self):
        return Profile.objects.filter(license_id= self.id).count()

    def count_active_profiles(self):
        return Profile.objects.filter(license_id= self.id).filter(is_active=True).count()

    def is_expired(self):
        return timezone.now() > self.expire_date

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

class Profile(AbstractBaseUser):
    email =models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=60, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, default=" ")
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=" ")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=" ")
    password1 = models.CharField(max_length=20,default= " ")
    password2 = models.CharField(max_length=20,default= " ")
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

My view.py

```
def regUser(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        print(form)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("/")
        else:
            return redirect("/youdiditwrong")
```

My HTML code

```
<HTML>
<head>
<title>Create a User</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>User: </h1>
<form action="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"/><br/>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname"/><br/>
Username: <input type="text" name ="username"/><br/>
Email:<input type="text" name="email"/><br/>
Password:<input type="text" name="password1"/><br/>
Confirm Password:<input type="text" name="password2"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Post"/>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us where are you loading your html from the views.py?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should look something like this, you have to add the jinja2 in the html, so that you can use the form you created

```html
<HTML>
<head>
<title>Create a User</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>User: </h1>
<form action="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<!-- This is the first option
{{ form.first_name }}
{{ form.last_name }}
{{ form.username }}
{{ form.email }}
{{ form.password }}
{{ form.password2 }}
-->
<!-- This is second option
{{ form.as_ul }}
-->
<input type="submit" value="Post"/>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

views.py

```py
def regUser(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        print(form)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("/")
        else:
            return redirect("/youdiditwrong")
    else: # if the method is not POST
        return render(request, "page with the html", 
    {"form": CustomUserCreationForm()}
```